# Wijmo Grid with Knockout bindings seems to redraw the entire table on updates?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, wijmo

I need to update a single cell at a time in the Wijmo Grid.  I am using Knockout bindings that populate the table and update cells, but it seems whenever I change a Knockout value for an element in the table, the entire table redraws, instead of just the single cell being changed.

Is there a way to update single cells in a table using Knockout without redrawing the entire table on each update?

Comment: I was expecting this too!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the default behavior of the grid because there might be other fields which might be bound to the same observable. I found the following forum post which discusses this issue in more detail : http://wijmo.com/topic/highlight-single-cell-updates-with-knockback.
Hopefully this may be incorporated in the near future.